# how to multicell remove border in fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I set Default value: 0.
bet border will be displayed..
how to overcome this problem?
Please tell me...

```
  while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) 
  {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) 
        {
        $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
        $pdf->Rect($x, $y, $widths[$i], $row_height);
        $pdf->MultiCell($widths[$i], $line_height,
        iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $row[$i]), 0, 'L');
        $x += $widths[$i];
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put in the EDGE location the value of 0[image]

1 : All borders -
0 : No Border -
L : Only Left boarder -
RT: Only Right and Top Border -
BTL: Only Bottom Top and Left side -
You can continue with other combinations of the borders.

Answer (score 1):

The border you see is created by the `Rect()` call before.

Answer (score 1):

Multicell Default border value is 0. Unless we specifying border as 1 , it will not display any border.

```
MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])
```

Refer FPDF documentation on Multicell http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

In the above question no border for multicell, so it will not display any border. But there is a rectangle, that displays the border.

```
Rect(float x, float y, float w, float h [, string style])
```

Refer FPDF documentation on Rect http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/rect.htm

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as indicated below.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) 
    {
        $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
        //$pdf->Rect($x, $y, $widths[$i], $row_height);
        $pdf->MultiCell($widths[$i], $line_height,
        iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $row[$i]), 0, 'L');
        $x += $widths[$i];
    }
}
```